# How to update packages using Nuget.exe

Tags: nuget

For my little sample projects in .NET (built directly on the command line without employing Visual Studio) I want to use directly `Nuget.exe` to retrieve the libraries I need, without having to commit them in the source repository.

I've been able to install them using the command

```
nuget install packages.config -o $destinationFolder
```

specifying the needed packages in a `packages.config` (like Nuget in Visual Studio).
However, I'm unable to update installed packages. I've tried to use this command

```
nuget update packages.config -r $destinationFolder
```

but `Nuget.exe` complains that is

```
unable to locate project file for '...packages.config'`.
```

I've searched on the Internet but I only find a [similar question](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/282743) in the Nuget discussion forums without answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've read the relevant source files in the Nuget project and I've discovered that for the update to succeed `Nuget.exe` needs to find a Visual C#/Basic/F# project.

I then created an empty `csproj` file in the folder and I've been able to update the packages I've installed before.

I've made a small sample at https://github.com/edymtt/nugetstandalone that shows how to install and update packages with `Nuget.exe`. I've also used a workaround to make sure that  only the latest versions of the libraries are kept in the folder.

**Update 2013-04-06 14:20 UTC** I've updated the sample to show how to achieve that using the [`-ExcludeVersion` flag of the `install` command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Install_Command).